# How to store comments of commit in database in Bitbucket Server?

Tags: bitbucket-server

I have Bitbucket Server, I can find commits in database but it doesn't store the message of commit. To get messages Bitbucket Server has api to get commits of repository but its only for specific branch (...bitbucket/rest/api/1.0/projects/PROJ/repos/test/commits?until=dev). Tried to write in until params "all-branches,all,*) doesn't work.

So to get all comments of each commit I have to get all projects, get branches and iterate each of them. I have 10+ projects and everyday new beaches are created.

I even added plugin from marketplace - "awesome graphs" its also doesn't store comments. It has api to load all commit of project but it returns html file, not sure it's a right way.

So how I can get all comments of commits and store new one commits made in database?